# Updating table in multi-threaded environment

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, transactions, spring-transactions

I have a table say CREDIT_POINTS. It has got below columns.

```
Copmany Credit points   Amount

A            100              50
B            200              94
C            250              80
```

There are multiple threads which will update this table. There is a method which reads **Credit points** and do some calculations and update **amount** as well as **Credit points**. This calculations will take quite some time.

Suppose thread A reads and it is doing some calculations. At the same time before A writes back thread B is reading data from table to does calculations and updates data. Here I am loosing the data which thread A updated. In many cases credit points and amount will not be in sync as multiple threads are reading and updating the table.

One thing we can do here is using a synchronized method. 
I am thinking of using spring transaction. Is spring transaction thread safe? What else is a good option for this?
Any help greatly appreciated.

Note: am using ibatis(ORM) and and MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need transactions to make sure, that you do your updates based on the data you previously read. This transaction must include read and write operation.
To make sure that multiple threads cooperate you do not need synchronized but have two options:

- pessimistic locking: you use select for update. This will set a lock which will be release at the end of the transaction.
- optimistic locking: during your update you find out, that the data has been changed meanwhile, if so you have to repeat reading and changing. You can achieve this in your update statement by not only searching for the company (the primary key, I hope), but also for the amount and "credit points" previously read.

Both methods have their merits. I recommend to make yourself familiar with these concepts before finishing this application. As soon as there is a heavy load, if you did anything wrong, your amounts and credit points might get wrongly calculated.

Comment: Using spring transaction solved my problem. Thanks aschoerk